# GeoIP Apache Mod Whitelist by Country and Local Network

Tags: security, apache2, geoip

I've been having issues with attempted hackers trying to break into my web server so I decided to block traffic from everywhere except my target countries: US, France, and Germany. I installed the [GeoIP Mod from MaxMind](https://github.com/maxmind/mod_maxminddb) and added the following Location block to my SSL-Site.conf file:

```
<Location "/">
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FR AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE DE AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
</Location>
```

Since implementing this policy, anyone outside of those three countries gets a 403, which is great! What's frustrating, though, is that I can no longer access the site from my internal network. Is there a way to add something like:

```
allow 192.168.1.0/24
```

I pieced together this configuration from guides and forums from across the web, so I realize it's not necessarily the best way to be doing my whitelist but I decided that since I know who should be accessing the server, there's no reason to keep it more open than it needs to be. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can just add:

```
allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

and that works. Why actual documentation for this doesn't exist is beyond me.

Comment: `allow from` is a standard apache configuration directive and is thus already documented with apache2.